# Can anyone tell the difference between find and findOne in yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

I've searched too much but stil do not understand the problem with the code above.

```
        $this->_entity_model = $entity_class_name::findOne(['service_request ' => $this->id]);
        $t = $entity_class_name::find()->where(['service_request ' => $this->id])->one();


        var_dump(isset($this->_entity_model));
        var_dump(isset($t));
        exit;
```

as you can see I've two queries, one with find and the other one with findOne.
Problem is : the first var_dump return false! the second true ?
I do not figure out how this can be possible ?

with the first query I get

'Key "service_request " is not a column name and can not be used as a filter'.

But the second is returning well(true) the result.

**$this->id is 127**

Update :

```
 $this->_entity_model = $entity_class_name::find()->where(['service_request' => $this->id])->one();
```

I now can use this but i get error below: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

my rules

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use app\components\Defaults;
 use Yii;

class IndividualTrader extends Entreprise
{ 
   const PROCESSING_IFU = 'processing_ifu';

public static function model($className = __CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

public function rules()
{
    return array_merge(parent::rules(),
        [
            [['service_request','integer']],
            [['emplois_generes','ca'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_FORM],
            [['identifiant_fiscal'], 'required', 'on' => self::PROCESSING_IFU],
            [['activite'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_ACTIVITY],
            [['forme_juridique'], 'default', 'value' => FormeJuridique::PP],
            [['emplois_generes'], 'number', 'min' => 0],

            [['objet_social'], 'default', 'value' => ''],
          //  [['identifiant_fiscal, activite, ville_taxe_professionnelle'], 'required', 'on' => 'fisc'],
            [['raison_sociale', 'identifiant_fiscal', 'registre_commerce'], 'unique'],
            /*[['has_nationalite'],'safe','on'=>self::SCENARIO_GUIDE],*/
            [['registre_commerce_declare', 'date_rc'], 'validateRequiredRegistrationData', 'registration_attribute' => 'has_already_registered_rccm', 'validate_if_value' => 1, 'on' => self::SCENARIO_FORM],
            [['telephone'], 'ext.LPNValidator.LPNValidator', 'defaultCountry' => Defaults::COUNTRY_PHONE_CODE, 'on' => self::SCENARIO_CONTACT],
            [['prenom_contact', 'nom_contact', 'telephone', 'email'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_CONTACT],
            [['activite'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_FORM],
            [['activite_secondaire'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'activite', 'operator' => '!=', 'message' => Yii::t('app', "{compareAttribute} and {attribute} must not be equal"), 'on' => self::SCENARIO_FORM],
            [['trade_name,company_name'], 'safe', 'on' => TradeNameSearch::SCENARIO_TRADE_NAME_SEARCH]
        ]
    );
}

public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    // initialize attributes with default values
    $this->debut_activite = date('d-m-Y');
    $this->forme_juridique = FormeJuridique::PP;
    $this->date_fin_activite = '31-12';
    $this->duree_activite = 99;
}

public function isCitizen()
{
    return $this->has_nationalite == 1;
}

public function isForeign()
{
    return isset($this->has_nationalite) && $this->has_nationalite == 0;
}

public function hasRegisteredRccm()
{
    return $this->has_already_registered_rccm == 0;
}

public function needsToProveAddress()
{
    return $this->has_director_different_address == 1;
}

public function getTotalSalaries()
{
    return intval($this->emplois_generes) + intval($this->emplois_etrangers);
}

public function isActivityAuthorizationRequired()
{
    return isset($this->is_activity_auth_needed) && $this->is_activity_auth_needed == 1;
}

public function isSpecialActivity()
{
    return (isset($this->is_activity_auth_needed) && $this->is_activity_auth_needed == 1) || (isset($this->is_import) && $this->is_import == 1);
}

public function hasCNI()
{
    return !isset($this->ppCommercant, $this->ppCommercant->type_piece_identite) ? false : ($this->ppCommercant->type_piece_identite == TypePieceIdentite::CNI);
}

public function getPrimaryAddress()
{
    $adres = (new Adresse())->findByAttributes(array('entreprise' => $this->id, 'type_adresse' => TypeAdresse::PRIMARY_ADDRESS));
    return ($adres->same_address_pp == 0) ? $this->getSecondaryAddress() : $adres;
}

public function getSecondaryAddress()
{
    return (new Adresse())->findByAttributes(array('entreprise' => $this->id, 'type_adresse' => TypeAdresse::SECONDARY_ADDRESS));
}

public function getInlinePrimaryAddress()
{
    $address = $this->getPrimaryAddress();
    return !isset($address) ? '' : $address->getInlineAdresse();
}


public function isPP()
{
    return true;
}

public function getRccmViewName()
{
    return '_pp';
}

/**
 * @param $name
 * @param string $operator
 * @return CDbCriteria
 */

public function getFullNameCriteria($name, $service_request_alias, $operator = 'AND')
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    //    $criteria->select = "(select CONCAT(pp.nom , CONCAT('|', CONCAT(pp.prenom ,CONCAT('|',ent.nom_commercial)))) from tbl_personne_physique pp, tbl_entreprise ent where pp.id = ent.pp_commercant and ent.service_request = ".$t.".id) as full_name";
    $full_name = "(select CONCAT(pp.nom , '|' , pp.prenom, '|' ,ent.nom_commercial) from tbl_personne_physique pp, tbl_entreprise ent where pp.id = ent.pp_commercant and ent.service_request = " . $service_request_alias . ".id)";
    $criteria->compare($full_name, $name, true, $operator);
    return $criteria;

}
}
```

Entreprise

```
use app\components\Utils;
use app\models\_base\BaseEntreprise;
use app\models\PieceJustificative;
use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveQuery;

class Entreprise extends BaseEntreprise
{
const WORKFLOW_ID = 'swEntreprise';
const STATUS_DRAFT = 'draft';
const STATUS_DRAFT_CORRECTION = 'draft_correction';
const STATUS_REVISION = 'revision';
const STATUS_REVISION_RETURNED = 'revision_returned';
const STATUS_TRAITEMENT = 'traitement';

// Workflow.
const STATUS_CORRECTION = 'correction';
const STATUS_RETRAIT = 'retrait';
const STATUS_PAIEMENT = 'paiement';
const STATUS_FINISHED = 'finished';
const STATUS_REJECTED = 'rejected';
const STATUS_ROLE_RC = 'role_rc';
const STATUS_ROLE_IF = 'role_if';
const STATUS_ROLE_PATENTE = 'role_patente';
const STATUS_ROLE_CAISSE = 'role_caisse';
const STATUS_VALID = 'valid';
const STATUS_RETURNED = 'returned';
const INSTRUCTION_PENDING = 0;
const INSTRUCTION_VALID = 1;
const INSTRUCTION_REJECTED = 2;
const REGISTRATION_RCCM = "RCCM";
const REGISTRATION_CC = "CC";
const RCCM = "RCCM";
const DGT = "DGT";
const CNSS = "CNSS";
const CARTE = "CARTE";
const ANNONCE = "ANNONCE";
const CNPS = "CNPS";
const DGI_IF = "IFU";
const DGI_TP = "TP";
const AL  ='AL';
const IMPORT = "IMPORT";
// SCENARIOS
const SCENARIO_GUIDE = 'guide';
const SCENARIO_FORM = 'form';
const SCENARIO_CONTACT = 'contact';
const SCENARIO_ACTIVITY_FORM = 'activity_form';
const SCENARIO_ACTIVITY = 'activite';
//DETERMINANTS
const EXPORT = "EXPORT";
const POUVOIR = "POUVOIR";
const MARIE = "MARIE";
const NATIONALITE = "NATIONALITE";
const CNI = "CNI";
const CASIER = "CASIER";
const HONNEUR = "HONNEUR";
const ASSOCIE_PP = "ASSOCIE_PP";
const ASSOCIE_PM = "ASSOCIE_PM";
const AGREMENT = "AGREMENT";
const PLUS = "+";
const MINUS = "-";
const DUREE_ACTIVITE = 99;
const DUREE_IF = 10;
const ONLINE = 1;
const OFFLINE = 2;
const COMMERCANT = 1;
const ENTREPRENANT = 3;
//PARAMS
const SOCIETE = 2;
private static $_role;
public $delai = 0;
/**
 * @var $keyword string
 * @var $name string
 * @var $service string
 */
public $keyword;
public $name;
public $service;
public $inscription;
private $_role_by_status = null;
private $_determinants;
private $_types_pieces;
private $_types_pieces_originaux;
private $_pieces_originaux;
private $_pieces_tobecertified;
private $_formulaires_tobesigned;
private $_is_PP;
private $_deletable;
private $_is_Entreprenant;

public static function model($className = __CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

public function rules()
{
    return array_merge(parent::rules(), [
        [['name', 'service','keyword', 'inscription'], 'safe'],
        //array('cc_titulaire, cc_titulaire_rpt, cc_suppleant, cc_suppleant_rpt', 'length', 'max' => 128),
        [['devise_capital','activite', 'mode_exploitation', 'journal_annonce'], 'string', 'max' => 500],
        [['date_fin_activite'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
        [['debut_activite', 'date_rc'], 'date', 'format' => Yii::$app->formatter->dateFormat, 'message' => Yii::t('app', 'The format of {attribute} is invalid.')],
        //array('exploitant_rccm', 'length', 'max' => 100),
        //array('exploitant_name', 'length', 'max' => 250),
        [['debut_activite'], 'date', 'format' => Yii::$app->formatter->dateFormat, 'message' => Yii::t('app', 'The format of {attribute} is invalid.')],
        [['email'], 'email'],
    ]);
}

public static function getCustomStatuslistData()
{
    return array(
        self::getStatusLbl(self::STATUS_DRAFT) => Yii::t('app', "STATUS_DRAFT"),
        self::getStatusLbl(self::STATUS_ROLE_CAISSE) => Yii::t('app', "STATUS_CAISSE"),
        self::getStatusLbl(self::STATUS_REVISION) => Yii::t('app', "STATUS_REVISION_CUSTOM"),
        self::getStatusLbl(self::STATUS_CORRECTION) => Yii::t('app', "STATUS_CORRECTION"),
        self::getStatusLbl(self::STATUS_ROLE_RC) => Yii::t('app', "STATUS_TRAITEMENT_RC"),
        self::getStatusLbl(self::STATUS_ROLE_IF) => Yii::t('app', "STATUS_TRAITEMENT_IF"),
        self::getStatusLbl(self::STATUS_ROLE_PATENTE) => Yii::t('app', "STATUS_TRAITEMENT_TP"),
        self::getStatusLbl(self::STATUS_RETRAIT) => Yii::t('app', "STATUS_RETRAIT_CUSTOM"),
        self::getStatusLbl(self::STATUS_FINISHED) => Yii::t('app', "STATUS_FINISHED"),
    );
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one main difference:

`Model::findOne()` is equal to `Model::find()->one()`.

In your case, you should try with:

```
$this->_entity_model = $entity_class_name::findOne(['service_request ' => $this->id]);
$t = $entity_class_name::find()->where(['service_request ' => $this->id])->one();


var_dump(isset($this->_entity_model));
var_dump(isset($t));
exit;
```

What probably happens is, there is no such record in the DB. Your first query sees that and returns null, but your second one returns an `ActiveRecord` object. One possible mistake I see is the extra space after `service_request`. Try deleting it, thus making the query:

```
$this->_entity_model = $entity_class_name::findOne(['service_request' => $this->id]);
```

Comment: Hello martin, thanks for your quick answer, 
I've done what you said I found where the problem comes from => 'service_request ' heer i have a espace that caused that error.

Comment: but another one is when I try with one I get => 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'

Comment: when I use $this->_entity_model = $entity_class_name::findOne(['service_request' => $this->id]);

Comment: can that be something to do with rules ?

Comment: Yes, it can. Try editing your question by adding the value of `var_dump($this->id)`, the rules in the model and how you later use that value.

Comment: it has 127 inside and the record exist in DB

Comment: As I said, add `->one()` at the end of the 2nd query, to get the same as `findOne()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201317/discussion-between-martin-dimitrov-and-muhammed-sami).

Answer (score 1):

For a better understanding of the differences in these methods, I will give examples to compare how you can get data from the database in both ways:

```
// find a single customer whose primary key value is 10
$customer = Customer::findOne(10);

// the above code is equivalent to:
$customer = Customer::find()->where(['id' => 10])->one();

// find the customers whose primary key value is 10, 11 or 12.
$customers = Customer::findOne([10, 11, 12]);

// the above code is equivalent to:
$customers = Customer::find()->where(['id' => [10, 11, 12]])->one();

// find the first customer whose age is 30 and whose status is 1
$customer = Customer::findOne(['age' => 30, 'status' => 1]);

// the above code is equivalent to:
$customer = Customer::find()->where(['age' => 30, 'status' => 1])->one();
```

The implementation of the method in the framework looks like this (in BaseActiveRecord.php):

```
   /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @return static|null ActiveRecord instance matching the condition, or `null` if nothing matches.
     */
    public static function findOne($condition)
    {
        return static::findByCondition($condition)->one();
    }
```

And method findByCondition:

```
    protected static function findByCondition($condition)
    {
        $query = static::find();

        if (!ArrayHelper::isAssociative($condition)) {
            // query by primary key
            $primaryKey = static::primaryKey();
            if (isset($primaryKey[0])) {
                // if condition is scalar, search for a single primary key, if it is array, search for multiple primary key values
                $condition = [$primaryKey[0] => is_array($condition) ? array_values($condition) : $condition];
            } else {
                throw new InvalidConfigException('"' . get_called_class() . '" must have a primary key.');
            }
        }

        return $query->andWhere($condition);
    }
```

Note that this method returns `return $query->andWhere($condition);`

This is the one difference.

In order for both options to return the same thing, the code needs to be changed like this:

```
$this->_entity_model = $entity_class_name::findOne(['service_request' => $this->id]);
```

//But where condition is similar andWhere in this case
        $t = $entity_class_name::find()->andWhere(['service_request' => $this->id])->one();

```
var_dump(isset($this->_entity_model));
var_dump(isset($t));
exit;
```

P.S.:'Key "service_request " is not a column name and can not be used as a filter'.

This is because a space is set in the column name `"service_request "`. Needed `"service_request"`

Answer (score 0):

Sergio highlights the main difference between using findOne and find().

The gotcha here can be if we've placed a pre-condition on our models 'find()' method.

ie:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 * @return \common\models\UserQuery the active query used by this AR class.
 */
public static function find()
{
    $query = new \common\models\UserQuery(get_called_class());
    
    return $query->where(['user.deleted_by' => 0]);

}
```

Now if we use `findOne($id)` or `findOne(['id'=>$id])` in our controller or elsewhere, the query condition will look like '`where user.deleted_by = 0 and id = 1`', which may or may not have the desired affect.
As Sergio said... we can mimic `findOne` with `find()->andWhere`... but not with `find()->where(['id' => $id])`.

`find()->where(['id' => $id])` is explicit in it's where clause and doesn't allow other conditions to be placed into it from somewhere else in the request.

Obviously to get a result without the pre-condition set in the Model::find() method... we can only use `find()->where(['id' => $id])`

I couldn't see the find() method in your Models, so this may not have been the issue at all... But I just had to mention this little gotcha to remind myself and maybe others that... these two are not quite the same :)